# cant access resources in new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, resources

Ive read through similiar questions and answers but am having a hard time understanding cause I am new to android development.

This statement gives me an ANR:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
```

I call this statement not from the main activity but from a second activity that I created. To me it screams scoping issues. Can someone lay some wisdom upon me as to why? I havent dont anything special with the intent (or anything else for that matter).

GameOverActivity.java:

```
public class GameOverActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() 
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
        {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public void yesResponse(View pView)
    {

        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        //Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

        //text.setVisibility(0);
        //addButton.setVisibility(0);
    }
}
```

The calling method from MainActivity.java:

```
public void checkTheBox()
{
    CheckBox tempBox;

    switch(boxNumberChecked)
    {
        case 0: 
        {
            tempBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tempBox.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            tempBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            tempBox.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }
        case 2: // intentionally falls through          
        default:
        {
            tempBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
            tempBox.setChecked(true);

            **Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);**
            break;
        }
    }
    boxNumberChecked++;
}
```

Comment: Show more of the code so we have some context and can see what you are doing. Most likely, `name_field` is not the `id` of an `EditText` in the xml you inflate in `setContentView()` (if you even inflate one)

Comment: please put your all code.so i can solve it.

Comment: Show ur xml code dude

Comment: @codeMagic - You were right about name_field not being an EditText type. You are amazing. Just curious, should I put all the values (such as strings, colors, etc.. in only one folder even though the two different activities have different values? It makes for a long list of string values in my XML file.

Comment: Thanks for everyones willingness to help, I appreciate it.

Comment: You should first **get he RootView** " thatAcitivityInstance.findViewById(android.R.id.content) " of that activity then you can access all the child View of that activity. let me know if you got me.

Comment: @user3011288 I'm not sure I understand but all `String`s can go in the `res/values/strings.xml` file. Colors will go in the `res/values/colors.xml` file.

Comment: @RDC The OP isn't inflating a different `layout` so no need for `thatActivityInstance`, just `findViewById(...)` works fine